# iTextSharp HTML to PDF using Font Awesome

Tags: pdf, itext, font-awesome, xmlworker

I am already successfully converting HTML to PDF using iTextSharp/XMLWorkerHelper. So far, I have been able to apply internal styling to the HTML as shown below. This works just fine. However, when I try to use a CDN to utilize Font Awesome, I am having no such luck.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how I'm converting the HTML to a memory stream which is ultimately used to create the PDF via `FileStreamResult` (the `FileStreamResult` is closing the memory stream).

```
        string html = "<html here>";
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var doc = new Document())
        {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {
                doc.Open();
                using (var srHtml = new StringReader(html))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                }
                writer.CloseStream = false;
                doc.Close();
            }
        }
```

**Why am I not able to see the briefcase on my generated PDF?**

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, iText does not support the `::before` or `:before` selectors which font awesome requires.

Comment: D'oh.. that's unfortunate